# Typescript/Javascript for loop on array, push value of a key to new array as key with the value 1 - if already exists, increment

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

The purpose is to have an array with all of the unique values for a specific key from another array. Those unique values (now keys in the new array) will have as value the number of times they appear in the original array.

This is my code so far:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


           let theStupidKey = data[i].DeliveryStatus;

           if (
             this.differentValuesOfStatus.indexOf(theStupidKey) == "-1"
           ) {
             this.differentValuesOfStatus.push(theStupidKey: 1);
             // this.differentValuesOfStatus[theStupidKey].push(theStupidKey = 1);
           }
           else {
             this.differentValuesOfStatus[theStupidKey] = 1
           }
        }
        console.log(this.differentValuesOfStatus);
      };
```

But the syntax is wrong and I tried everything I could think of to make it work.

Basically I'm looping through an array.

If the value of the 'deliverystatus' key does not exist in the second array, I'm adding it with the value of "1".

If it already exists, I want to add another number to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can only hold a list of values.  If you want to store keys and corresponding values, you should be using a map:

```
class Test {
  differentValuesOfStatus: Map<string, number>;

  test(data: {DeliveryStatus: string}[]) {
    this.differentValuesOfStatus = new Map<string, number>();
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let theStupidKey = data[i].DeliveryStatus;

      let value = this.differentValuesOfStatus.get(theStupidKey);
      this.differentValuesOfStatus.set(theStupidKey,
        (value === undefined ? 0 : value) + 1);
    }
    console.log(this.differentValuesOfStatus);
  }
}

let t = new Test();
t.test([
  { DeliveryStatus: "Accepted" },
  { DeliveryStatus: "Rejected" },
  { DeliveryStatus: "Accepted" }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an object, put your status name as Key and occurrence number as value. here is the code to achieve this.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    let theStupidKey = data[i].DeliveryStatus;

    if (!this.differentValuesOfStatus.hasOwnProperty(theStupidKey)) {
        this.differentValuesOfStatus[theStupidKey] = 0;
    }
    this.differentValuesOfStatus[theStupidKey] = this.differentValuesOfStatus[theStupidKey] + 1;
}
console.log(this.differentValuesOfStatus);
```

you will get resposne like this.

```
{Status1: 2, Status2: 3, Status3: 1, Status4: 3}
```

But if you want it an array you can do something like this,

```
let newArray = [];
for (var key in this.differentValuesOfStatus) {
    newArray.push({ "Status": key, "Occurence": this.differentValuesOfStatus[key] });
}
console.log(newArray);
```

output will be

```
[{status: "Status1", Occurence: 2},
{status: "Status2", Occurence: 3},
{status: "Status3", Occurence: 1},
{status: "Status4", Occurence: 3}]
```